# Why does creating a layered bar chart remove sorting?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to use [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html) to create a stacked bar chart. I would like to label each bar with the percent of the total of all bars in descending order. Here's how I create two layers (one for the bars, one for the labels):

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('AAAABBBB'),
                    'b': list('xxyyxxyy'),
                    'c': [2, 7, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4]})

df2 = df1.groupby('a', as_index=False).sum()
df2['pct'] = (df2['c'] / df2['c'].sum()).round(2)

bars = alt.Chart(df1).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('c', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 22])),
    y=alt.Y('a', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='c', order='descending')),
    color='b',
)
text = alt.Chart(df2).mark_text(dx=15).encode(
    x='c',
    y=alt.Y('a', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='c', order='descending')),
    text='c'
)
```

Each layer is sorted in the correct order and looks good. But when I combine them, the sorting is reset and they are no longer sorted descending.

```
both = bars + text
both
```

[image: bar chart in wrong order]

How can I keep the bars sorted when combining layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting of unioned domains is not supported in Vega-Lite. If you open the javascript console for your chart, or if you [view it in the vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-tS3PGoF8REzzNK2dAOf7ua8BQ5R7zDLCXpAACQAzgSHw8ahqP4YAD066eqHEADpUNnaFp8rvkLB1-OCBItwQd-4lNmCFu+LuGLumLuAFZU+DfGoyv4CGoP50XaGUghCMJIhieIkhSdJMmyPJCmKRBSnKKwfhwcUoAAQQZHYGiOEQviwQIkzIHDIHwkRCKgYjO1IOIKOwnwaKgOjUQZUiwAYFjICo9jGh8NESNIaJ+KogAhAifAYmBSHIilbAEnwZNouTuNINJJLU2SGlExisAiXSGnUjiRK0rA+LaKc2lFAJ5UVZVVTidVNW1RJdX1ZgjRNM0LUwoZWIaISeOiBgRDUaAaTAD8GAk5TKL0sSyKhSBotij8ckScdYUMBFBCAA), you'll see the warning that Vega-Lite produces:

```
[Warning] Dropping sort property {"field":"c","op":"sum","order":"descending"} as unioned domains only support boolean or op "count".
[Warning] Dropping sort property {"field":"c","op":"mean","order":"descending"} as unioned domains only support boolean or op "count".
```

The relevant Vega-Lite bug is here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5048.

You can avoid this if you build both layers from the same dataset; for example:

```
bars = alt.Chart(df1).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('c:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 22])),
    y=alt.Y('a:N', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='c', op='sum', order='descending')),
    color='b:N',
)

text = alt.Chart(df1).mark_text(dx=15).encode(
    x='sum(c):Q',
    y=alt.Y('a:N', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='c', op='sum', order='descending')),
    text=alt.Text('sum(c):Q')
)

bars + text
```

[image]